# jQuery remote form inside a regular form - remote form is hidden

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a page for editing an object (a Group object as it happens) that has a search form inside it, which should refresh the list of people available to add to the group.  I want to set it up so that the inner form is a remote form, calling "/groups/person_search".  This means that the submit button to the remote form should not submit the outer "group" form.

Here's what i have at the moment - in my rails template (with some sections cut out for clarity):

```
<%= form_for @group, :class => "disable_empty_fields" do |f| %>  
  <div class="main">

    <%= f.label :name, "Group name" %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :size => "60" %><br/>    

    <%= f.label :description, "Group description" %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :description, :size => "60x8" %><br/>

    <div class="section peoplesearch">
      <%= form_tag "/groups/person_search", :method => :get, :class => "xxx", :remote => true do %>
        <div class="block">
          <div class="main">
            <label>Search</label>
            <%= text_field_tag "search[term]", params[:search][:term], :class => "searchinput", :placeholder => "Search for someone" %>
            <%= button_to_function "Go", "jQuery(this).parents('form').eq(0).submit();" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div><!-- /.section -->
  </div><!-- /.main -->        
  <div class="block submitblock">
    <div class="main">
      <button type="submit">Save</button>                                    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block cancelblock">
    <div class="main">
      <%= link_to "<b>X</b> Cancel changes".html_safe, task_path(@group), :class => "button" %>        
    </div>
  </div>                
<% end %>
```

and in the generated html:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/groups/1" class="edit_group" id="edit_group_1" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="vxGXV8vv2gvuk+7IIQwwsHcvFoVvET/h7eHcQUKuMco=" />
  </div>  
  <div class="main"> 
    <label for="group_name">Group name</label><br/> 
    <input id="group_name" name="group[name]" size="60" type="text" value="First group" /><br/>    
    <label for="group_description">Group description</label><br/> 
    <textarea cols="60" id="group_description" name="group[description]" rows="8">blah blah</textarea><br/> 

    <div class="section peoplesearch"> 
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="groups/person_search" class="xxx" data-remote="true" method="get">
        <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
          <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
        </div> 
        <div class="block"> 
          <div class="main"> 
              <label>Search</label> 
            <input class="searchinput" id="search_term" name="search[term]" placeholder="Search for someone" type="text" /> 
              <input onclick="jQuery(this).parents('form').eq(0).submit();" type="button" value="Go" /> 
          </div> 
        </div> 
      </form> 
    </div>
  </div> <!-- /main -->
  <div class="block submitblock"> 
    <div class="main"> 
      <button type="submit">Save</button>                                    
    </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="block cancelblock"> 
    <div class="main"> 
      <a href="/tasks/1" class="button"><b>X</b> Cancel changes</a>        
    </div> 
  </div>    
</form>
```

The "xxx" class on the form is just so i could find it quickly in the page source.

Looking at the generated html, it all looks fine, but when i click on the 'Go' button, which should submit the inner form, it's submitting the outer form.  The inner form doesn't show up in chrome's dom inspector, and doing `jQuery("form").size()` in the console gives me `1`, again as if the inner form isn't there, even though i *can* see it in the page source.

It's probably something dumb, can someone set me straight?  cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML does not support nested forms.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)  HTML5 does allow the connection of inputs to forms independent of the document structure.

Comment: ah right - particularly the part about some browsers treating the inner </form> as the end tag to the outer <form>.  So, i guess i need to do something like: have a div instead, and have the (pseudo-)submit button of the inner form collect all the inputs inside that div and push them into the data of an ajax call?  Is there a simpler way?